# run php function on click of <a> tag

Tags: php, function

Ive got a php function that packages all files of a type in a directory into a zip file and downloads it.

Ive set the index.php to shows me all the files in the directory so i can download individual files as needed.

What ive done is put the zip script into a function called 'create_zip'. What i want to be able to do is call the 'create_zip' on click of an `<a>` tag.

How can i do this ? Becuase if i `include` the function it will just run as soon as i load the page..

the html im using for the  tag is really simple like this

```
<a href="<!--Run create_zip function-->">Download all files</a>
```

Comment: You have to use AJAX for this.

Comment: Directly not possible html runs on your clients browser php runs on your server - you will need to create 'page' that will generate the zip. You can use ajax to call this behind scenes but just as good you can use direct link with target="_blank"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to do this via using ajax, i.e

First create a file, which you can call once the link has been clicked, for this example, well call it download.php

Then in the file add a call to your function....

```
<?
// execute function to get files
$zip_file = create_zip();
// get the full path to zip file
$full_zip_path = '/path/to/zip/file'.$zip_file;

// You may need to do more here depending on how far your create zip function goes

// if you want it to force the download you can then do this

header("Pragma: public"); // required
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers 
header("Content-Type: octet/stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$zip_file.";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($full_zip_path));
readfile($full_zip_path);
exit();

?>
```

Then add a class to your a tag, as such...

```
<a href="<!--Run create_zip function-->" class="download-zip">Download all files</a>
```

Then what you want is some javascript to call load the php file in the background, basically add this somewhere in your footer/header (depending on where your scripts are).

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("a.download-zip").click(function() {

    window.location.href = "/path/to/php/file/download.php";
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

That will then load the file in the background, which will in turn force a download of the created zip file. Some of the above may be slightly out due to not seeing how far your create_zip function goes, but it should set you on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

That's very simple:

```
<a href="/path/to/myphpfile.php">Download all files</a>
```

then just add you zip function to myphpfile.php

myphpfile.php

```
<?php create_zip(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call it like an url:

`<a href="/download-all-files.php">Download all files</a>`

And then it'll do the job for you.
Problem: it'll open a new page, the user will have to return to the previous one manually.
You might want to include the code in the actual page and, call the link with a parameter:

`<a href="actual-page.php?download-all">Download all files</a>`

On your function you can check the parameter (something close to this):

```
if ($['GET'] == "download-all") {
   download all
}
```

An AJAX call, as Steve suggested is also a good idea, though I'm not sure on how to handle the incoming zip file.

Comment: Output the page into a hidden IFrame, I use it like that for file upload :P

Comment: Just posted it down here, really easy to do it in an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Just found my script

So you create a hidden iframe

```
<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" style="display: none;" src="#"></iframe>
```

Then you create a form with some button

```
<form action="path/to/downloadzip.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target"> //target will tell the browser to run it in the iFrame with name="upload_target"
```

then in downloadzip.php:

```
<?php create_zip(); ?> //and output the file here
```

This will download the zip without having to load a new page

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the request back to the server in order to do this.

For example, you would use a link that pointed to a PHP page on your server that would run the function and give you the result:

```
<a href="RunMyFunction.php">Download all files</a>
```

You could also submit this in the background using and AJAX request, but this is an optional extra.

Answer (score 0):

better way you can use ajax post 
You can try calling ajax on click on hyperlink (give it identity like class).

$('.classHyper').click(function() {
//do ajax post
});